# CURL error - Bigcommerce Webhooks

Tags: php, curl, webhooks, bigcommerce

I am attempting to curl into the bigcommerce webhooks... although I am getting an error that I cannot figure out.

Any ideas?

```
JSON::ParserError at /token
```

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/api/webhooks/event_triggers
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/api/webhooks/quickstart

```
<?php

    //set POST variables
    $url = 'https://hooks-beta.bigcommerce.com/token';
    $fields = array(
    "client_id"=>"client_id_goes_here",
    "client_secret"=>"client_secret_goes_here",
    "user"=>"demo",
    "token"=>"token_goes_here",
    "store_domain"=>"https://domain_goes_here.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2"
        );

    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields); 
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 

    $result = curl_exec($ch); 
        if ($result === false) {
            echo '<textarea>'.curl_error($ch).'</textarea>'; 
        } else {
            echo "<textarea>".$result."</textarea>";
        }
        curl_close($ch);
    ?>
```

Comment: What does the returned json look like?

Comment: That's not the json, the json from `https://hooks-beta.bigcommerce.com/token` looks like `{"error":"No such hook exist!"}`

Comment: So where is that parser error on /token occurring?

Right, it theoretically should be returning something similar to...

    {"access_token":"[webHooksAccessToken]","producer":"store/[myStoreKey]"}

reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352146/bigcommerce-webhooks-listener-in-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by json_encoding my array.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
```